# Proving Lebesgue measurability of $E$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that a set $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ an open set $U$, containing $E$, such that $m^{*}(U\backslash E)\le \varepsilon$.
I was able to prove $\implies$ direction. I need to prove the other direction, i.e. I need to show E is Lebesgue measurable. I tried using Caratheodory Criterion but I got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, take an open $U_n$ containing $E$ such that $m^*(U_n\setminus E)\leq \frac{1}{n}$. Then, consider the set $U:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$. We know open sets are Lebesgue measurable, hence $U$ is as well. What do we know about $m^*(U\setminus E)$? So what can we say about $E$?